# Fill memory with a constant in Trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm new to Trace32 and symply trying to fill 174bytes, starting from a given adress, with the same value (sometimes 0x00, sometimes 0XFF).

Looking at the documentation, Data.Set seems to be the way to go but I can't figure out the correct arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command is in fact Data.Set

```
 Data.Set <address>|<addr.range> %<access width> <value(s)> [/<option>]
```

Data.Set can be used to set a value to a single address or to set a value repetitively inside an address range.

So how to define an address range? There are two options

- <first addr.>--<last addr.>
- <first addr.>++<number of following addresses>

Putting all together: To set 0xFF to 174 Bytes starting from 0x1000 you have to write

```
 Data.Set 0x1000++173. %Byte 0xFF
```

Note the trailing dot after 173, which identifies decimal numbers. Without the dot the number would be interpreted as a hexadecimal value (unless you used SETUP.RADIX Decimal)